# How to use Java processBuilder class where input command argument values have dash characters

Tags: java

I would like to run an app from my service using the java processBuilder class however that app has command line arguments that have values that have dashes in them.

e.g. >app -b 8 -e u-law

when I create a processBuilder instance and pass in "-e u-law" as one of the command arguments, it can't seem to handle the dash in the argument value. Is there a way around this to get it working?

Comment: you need to escape the dash?

Comment: @charlesbabbage: no. Rather he needs to separate the tokens in the command String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add each String *token*, that is, each command sub-String that is separated by white space, separately to the ProcessBuilder's command parameter array or List. For this command line,

```
e.g. >app -b 8 -e u-law
```

You have 5 String tokens, app, -b, 8, -e, and u-law (since you have no gap between the u and the dash). You could then do something like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("app"); 
list.add("-b");
list.add("8"); 
list.add("-e"); 
list.add("u-law");
ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(list);
```

alternatively you could use an array of 5 Strings for this,

```
String[] commands = {"app", "-b", "8", "-e", "u-law"};
ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks for such a quick response, much appreciated. What I was missing was that every string had to be a separate entry. For arguments like: -c 1 .... I thought I could put that in one string entry: "-c 1" and same goes for the other value that had a dash in it: -e u-law ... I even tried separate strings for that one, but missed the separate strings for the other ones where only space is involved. It works now. Thanks!